# Compare two dictionaries with one key in common and form a new dictionary combining the remaining keys associated with this common key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, one contains the name and initial values of some registers and the other contains the name and address values of those same registers.

I need to compare the two dictionaries on register names [id] and then take the initial value of a register [initValue] from dictionary 1 and the address values [addrValue] from dictionary 2 and put them in a new dictionary so that the key in this new dictionary becomes the address rather than the register name.

Below is what I am doing but I don't know how to merge the two dictionary keys.

```
regex = "(?P<id>\w+?)_INIT\s*?=.*?'h(?P<initValue>[0-9a-fA-F]*)"
for x in re.findall(regex, lines):
    init_list = (x.groupdict()["id"], "0x" + x.groupdict()["initValue"])

regex = "(?P<id>\w+?)_ADDR\s*?=.*?'h(?P<addrValue>[0-9a-fA-F]*)"
for y in re.findall(regex, lines):
    addr_list = (y.groupdict()["addr_id"], "0x" + y.groupdict()["addrValue"])

for key in set(init_list['init_id'].keys()).union(addr_list['id'].keys()):
    if init_list[key] == addr_list[key]
        expect_by_addr = dict (addr_list['addrValue']   # something here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the first two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
for x in range(0, 10):
    dict1[x] = "initValue{}".format(x)
    y = x+3
    dict2[y] = "address{}".format(y)
```

Combine them based on dict2 "addresses"

```
dict3 = {}
#Note because you want the addresses to be the key of the new dictionary
#we only need to look at the keys that exist in both dict1 and dict2.
for key in dict2.keys():
    if key in dict1:
        dict3[dict2[key]] = dict1[key]
```

Dictionaries:

```
dict1
{0: 'initValue0', 1: 'initValue1', 2: 'initValue2', 3: 'initValue3', 4: 'initValue4', 5: 'initValue5', 6: 'initValue6', 7: 'initValue7', 8: 'initValue8', 9: 'initValue9'}

dict2
{3: 'address3', 4: 'address4', 5: 'address5', 6: 'address6', 7: 'address7', 8: 'address8', 9: 'address9', 10: 'address10', 11: 'address11', 12: 'address12'}

dict3 (combined)
{'address5': 'initValue5', 'address4': 'initValue4', 'address7': 'initValue7', 'address6': 'initValue6', 'address3': 'initValue3', 'address9': 'initValue9', 'address8': 'initValue8'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you build a single dict in a single pass?

```
from collections import defaultdict

r_line = re.compile(r"(?P<id>\w+?)_(?P<type>[A-Z]+)\s*?=.*?'h(?P<value>[0-9a-fA-F]*)")

register_ids = defaultdict(dict)

for match in r_line.finditer(lines):
    groups = match.groupdict()
    key = groups['type'].tolower()
    # store as int. You can use `hex()` or format codes for display as hex
    value = int(groups['value'], 16)
    register_ids[groups['id']][key] = value
```

It's not a problem if you have multiple sets of lines: it will just update `register_ids` with new data:

```
for lines in lines_list:
    for match in r_line.finditer(lines):
        ...
```

This will produce a single dict `ids` that looks like this:

```
{'register1': {'addr': 1234, 'init': 5678, ...}, 'register2': {...}, ...}
```

You can then produce any other kind of derived dictionary you want very easily. For example, for your initial values keyed by addresses:

```
addresses = {}
for values in register_ids.itervalues():
    try:
        addresses[values['addr']] = values['init']
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: The reason I cant build a single dictionary is because I get these values from a verilog file which is divided into two parts.The first half contains 16 bit register address and the second half contains the corresponding 8 bit initialization values of those eregisters.So I have to build two dictionaries and then merge based on register names. e.g `localparam OSD_MODE_15_H_ADDR = 16'h038d;`
`localparam OSD_MODE_15_H_INIT = 8'h23;`

Comment: I don't understand why that is a problem since both parts of the file use the same registry names, right? Why would the code I posted not work? (Notice I changed your regex to be more generic.)

Comment: there is a slight difference in the names.The register address part of the file has the _ADDR append to the register name and the value part has _INIT in the register name.So I have to first stip off the _ADDR and _INIT to get the common register name.

Comment: Instead of doing that, do what my code does: capture the 'ADDR' or 'INIT' with the same regex (here it's the "type" group), and produce key names dynamically. Even if you use two regexes, you can simply update the same dict `register_ids` with a different key name. I get the impression that you have simply dismissed the "do it on one pass" idea without actually examining the approach or reading my answer.

Comment: I just tested your code...i think this will work as it separates out the _ADDR and _INIT part...thank you so much!

Comment: @serendipity Be sure to accept this as the answer since it solves your problem.

Comment: @rdp I tested both your solutions and both work very well up till the creation of the third dictionary.The third dictionary is empty and gives me key errors

Comment: Updated, but it was a very minor change.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the code is related to your question.

But let us assume you have two dicts. `dictA` and `dictB` (below are example dicts):

```
>>> dictA = dict.fromkeys(range(10), {'initial_val_1': 'value_a', 'initial_val_2': 'value_b' })
>>> dictB = dict.fromkeys(range(5, 15), {'address': 'my_address'})
```

Code you need:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> shared_keys = set(dictA.keys()).intersection(set(dictB.keys()))
>>> combined = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for key in shared_keys:
    combined[key].update(dictA[k])
    combined[key].update(dictB[k])
```

View the dictionary:

```
>>> for k, v in combined.items():
    print k, v

5 {'initial_val_2': 'value_b', 'initial_val_1': 'value_a', 'address': 'my_address'}
6 {'initial_val_2': 'value_b', 'initial_val_1': 'value_a', 'address': 'my_address'}
7 {'initial_val_2': 'value_b', 'initial_val_1': 'value_a', 'address': 'my_address'}
8 {'initial_val_2': 'value_b', 'initial_val_1': 'value_a', 'address': 'my_address'}
9 {'initial_val_2': 'value_b', 'initial_val_1': 'value_a', 'address': 'my_address'}
```

Comment: What I currently have is `init_list = {id: abcd , init_value: 0x23}` and `addr_list = {id: abcd , addr:0x2121}` and what I need is `new_dict = {addr: (0x2121,0x23)}` i.e for every matching id abcd in the two dictionaries I want to combine the corresponding address 0x2121 and value 0x23 such that when I input the address what I get out is the value at that address. Sorry for not being very clear as I myself am trying to understand the problem.

Comment: I understood your problem. I am not going to spend my time creating an answer you can copy-paste into your solution. The logic part is titled "Code you need" if you use your dictionaries in place of dictA and dictB it should work fine. Try it and see.